# Use of if statements to know if the user has created a post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a django project in which a user can make a post and select the category the post should be in. My current code has 2 categories('action' and 'sports') using 4 views, 1 view displays all of the categories, 1 that contains the form to upload the post and the other 2 views display just one of the categories. I want to make that all users that have made a post can see other peoples posts, if not they have to create one; this is kind of a problem since if the user types the url on the browser, the user will be able to see other people's posts even if the user hasn't create one. I know there should be some if statements on the views.py file, but I have already tried multiple ways to do this and it just still dont work. Any idea to solve this problem helps.

models.py

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('action', 'action'),
    ('sports', 'sports'),
)

class Mates(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usermates', unique=True)
    categories = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default="choose...", max_length=10)
    req_bio = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    req_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='requestmates_pics', null=True, blank=True, default=False)
```

views.py (matesmain displays all of the posts, mates_action just posts related to the action category, mates_sports just for sports category and mates displaysthe form to create a post)

```
def matesmain(request):
    contents = Mates.objects.all()
    action = Mates.objects.filter(categories='action')
    sports = Mates.objects.filter(categories='sports')
    
    context = {
        'contents': contents,
        'action' : action,
        'sports' : sports,
    }
    print("nice3")
    return render(request, 'mates.html', context)

def mates_action(request):
    action = Mates.objects.filter(categories='action')

    context = {
        'action' : action,
    }
    print("nice3")
    return render(request, 'mates-action.html', context)

def mates_sports(request):
    sports = Mates.objects.filter(categories='sports')

    context = {
        'sports' : sports,
    }
    print("nice3")
    return render(request, 'mates-sports.html', context)



def mates(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_mates = MatesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_mates.is_valid():
            instance = form_mates.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('mates-main')
            print('succesfully uploded')

    else:
        form_mates = MatesForm()
        print('didnt upload')
    return redirect('mates-main')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mates', views.mates, name='mates'),
    path('mates-main', views.matesmain, name='mates-main'),
    path('mates/action', views.mates_action, name='mates-action'),
    path('mates/sports', views.mates_sports, name='mates-sports'),

]
```

If you have any questions, please let me know in the comments;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to the user, that way with an IF you can ask like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

def has_posts(self):
    if Post.objects.filter(user=self).count() > 0:
        return True
    return False

User.add_to_class("has_posts",has_posts)

def some_view(request):

    if request.user.has_posts():
        return the view
    else:
        return (redirect to error view)
```

Comment: Hey Guillermo! so basically all I have to do is add the has_posts to the models.py file right?

Comment: Also the code on "same-view" is what I have to add to my the 3 main views (mate-sports, mates-action and mates)

Comment: never mind I added your code to views.py file and it worked! Thankyou;)

Comment: Beautiful @JuanMartinZabala